# How can I make it so the dropdown menu stays there when I'm hovering on it?

Tags: html, css

I have the following dropdown menu:

```
<div id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li>
        <a href=""></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

#header .navigation {
    float: right;
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
#header .navigation li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
#header .navigation li a {
    float: left;
}
#header .navigation li:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.0s ease 0s;
}
#header .navigation > li > .sub-menu {
    display: none;
    width: 150px;
    transition: all 0.0s ease 0.2s;
    padding: 10px 15px 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
}
#header .navigation > li > .sub-menu li {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    width: 100% ;
}
#header .sub-menu .sub-menu li {
    padding: 10px 0 0 15px;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

The problem is that the `.sub-menu` disappears immediately after I leave the parent. How can I make it so that `.sub-menu` stays where it is as long as I'm hovering it?

Here's a live example: http://m2c.dreamhosters.com/wordpress/

Comment: can you fiddle it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to note:

- place any padding on the links themselves, as you don't want any gaps between the top `li` and the sub `ul`s
- make sure the sub `ul` is neatly tucked at the bottom of the top `li`, with top: 100%. (That prevents any gap between them.

E.g.

```css
#header .navigation {
    float: right;
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
#header .navigation li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
#header .navigation li a {
    float: left;
}
#header .navigation li:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.0s ease 0s;
}
#header .navigation li .sub-menu {
    display: none;
    width: 150px;
    transition: all 0.0s ease 0.2s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
#header .navigation > li > .sub-menu li {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}


ul, li {list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div id="header">
<ul class="navigation">
  <li>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>text</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem lies on this line of code:

```
top: 20px;
```

If you do a very fast move of your mouse from the list item anchor tag to the `.sub-menu`, the `.sub-menu` won't disappear.

So what you've gotta do is to reduce the gap from `a` to `.sub-menu`.

For example you can change `top: 20px;` to `padding-top: 20px;`, it would do the trick. However the style might change.

UPDATE:
For the link you provided, you can simply change `top: 20px;` to `top: 15px`.